# Custom popup for key of keyboard

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I am making custom keyboard..
Now my question is that I want custom popup for key pressed. 
So, can I change it. 
popup of key like as this image

[image]

If any one know about this then please help me...

**CapDroid**

Comment: hi CapDroid i am working on soft keyboard, have you succeed to create custom pop up.Because i just need to customize default pop up window.I had posted my question here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299210/customize-soft-keyboard-key-preview"

Answer (score 4):

Yup, its not too hard at all. Just check out the time in the AOSP [here.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master)
It's all done in the resource files, here is a short snippet. From the `symbols.xml` file of my keyboard project.

```
<Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
     android:popupKeyboard="@xml/kbd_popup_template"
     android:popupCharacters="¹½⅓¼⅛"/>
```

Comment: @Schwiz.. Hi, I am following SoftKeybaord example(SDK) but I cant find my solution in that example..

Comment: @CapDroid my mistake its the AOSP that has the example, I updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Schwiz.. Thanks, Dear but it working fine only on long click. On Single Click default popup is display.. & Another thing is I am using custom layout for keyboard instead of keyboard control.....

Comment: @CapDroid ahh sorry I misunderstood your question. I looked into it for you but can't find an immediate solution. Hope you find your answer!

Comment: how to make style in keyPreview look like above image

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Just set the `android:iconPreview` attribute for the key, where `my_icon_preview` is the drawable for the preview popup.

In XML:

```
<Key android:codes="116"
     android:keyLabel="t"
     android:iconPreview="@drawable/my_icon_preview" />
```

In Java:

```
tKey.iconPreview = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon_preview);
```

Where `tKey` has the type `Keyboard.Key` (of course).

Comment: Not sure from your question if you're trying to customize the symbol or the background. This answer customizes the symbols.

Comment: if in case i need to change just background color of key preview?