# android keyboard popout, how is it made?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I'm trying to make an android keyboard and was wondering how to make a letter pop out, when it is hit.

I tried using a custom dialog, but it totally would not work within `InputMethodService`.

crashes with:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17125): at 
    keyboard.rob.com.TotalKeyboard$3.onTouch(TotalKeyboard.java:527)
```

when `dialog.show();` is called.

So, supposedly some other method would be needed.

I have the sample keyboard code, but couldn't find the place where it show a popout letter. Yet I'm sure it doesn't use dialogs.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988699/custom-popup-for-key-of-keyboard see if these answers help.

Comment: also check this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android

Answer (score 1):

Could be using a FrameLayout with a drawing canvas stacked at the nearest index. When someone selects a letter, it draws that letter on the top index of the frame layout.