# How to avoid char popup in android keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

[image: Android soft keyboard]

I don't want to show the char suggestion when I click on any key. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think and as per I know that we can't disable this PopUp for Android Keyboard..
But it is possible to disable or change(layout) of PopUp when we create our own custom keyboard..

if you want create your own custom keyboard and you want change or disable PopUp then this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988699/custom-popup-for-key-of-keyboard) will be help you..