# customize soft keyboard key preview

Tags: customization, android-softkeyboard, keypreview

> I am **working on soft keyboard**. I had done with all of my functionality.
>
> But now i just need to **change view of key preview**  when key is
>   pressed. Currently my key preview is shown(default sample keyboard key
>   preview) like shown in below image,

[image]

> As we can see character 'd' is popped up when key is pressed.
>
> But now i need customize it.  As **currently key preview background is
>   white, i need it to set green color** just like shown below,

[image]

> I have the sample keyboard code, but couldn't find the place where it
>   show a popout letter. So i can easily edit it customize it my own way.
>
> I googled for help nothing found any help any. Any help is
>   appreciated.

Comment: This question solved here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911409/make-popup-of-the-key-pressed-in-a-customized-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your keys XML layout:

```
<Key android:codes="97" android:keyIcon="@drawable/key_icon" android:iconPreview="@drawable/key_preview_icon" />
```

It worked for me. I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have created a `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.xml` layout resource file

Use `android:keyBackground="#FF419F3C"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:labelTextSize="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorTrybg"        
    android:keyTextColor="@color/colorTrykey"
              <!-- This one -->
    android:keyBackground="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview">
</android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>
```