# Make popup of the key pressed in a customized keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm using keyboardview to have my own keyboard.

Works fine, but I cannot do the effect of enlarging the key pressed, as does the Android keyboard

[image: zoom image]

These are the parts that use

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        style="@style/Widget.KeyboardView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:shadowRadius="0"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

.

```
   <style name="Widget.KeyboardView" parent="android:Widget.KeyboardView">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/naranja</item>
            <item name="android:keyBackground">@drawable/naranja</item>
            <item name="android:keyTextSize">40sp</item>
            <item name="android:keyTextColor">#d35400</item>
            <item name="android:keyPreviewLayout">@layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard</item>
            <item name="android:keyPreviewOffset">12dp</item>
            <item name="android:keyPreviewHeight">80dp</item>  
            <item name="android:popupLayout">@layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard</item>
        </style>
```

.

XML/popup:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:keyHeight="10%p">
</Keyboard>
```

Rows

```
     <Key
                android:codes="81"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
                android:keyLabel="Q"
                android:popupCharacters="Q"
                android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" />

    etc...
```

I've tried with onKey method, also from the XML. But without success.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For just showing the enlarged previews, `KeyboardView` should be doing it by default. You don't want to set a `popupKeyboard` value as this is for a special mini keyboard that shows on long presses.

I assume you were following [this tutorial](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm). Take note of these lines in section 3.3:

```
// Do not show the preview balloons
mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
```

Instead set this to `true`.

**Complete Solution**

*In your activity's layout:*

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:keyPreviewOffset="12dp"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/kbpreview"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

The important properties here are `keyPreviewLayout`, `keyPreviewOffset` and `keyPreviewHeight`.

*layout/kbpreview.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

*xml/kb.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="12.50%p"
    android:keyHeight="10%p" >

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="55"    android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="56"    android:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key android:codes="57"    android:keyLabel="9" />
        <Key android:codes="65"    android:keyLabel="A" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
        <Key android:codes="66"    android:keyLabel="B" />
        <Key android:codes="55006" android:keyLabel="CLR" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <!-- and whatever else... -->

</Keyboard>
```

*In your activity code*

```
    Keyboard mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.kb);

    // Lookup the KeyboardView
    KeyboardView mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardview);

    // Attach the keyboard to the view
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);

    // Key listener required
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(myListener);
```

**Result**

with the '5' key pressed:

[image]

You may also find it useful to check out the [`KeyboardView` source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java).

Comment: i want to show keypreview onLong Press event of keyboardview is that is possible